# how to upload a zipped folder in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload

I am new in codeigniter, even in PHP.
I want to upload a zipped folder which may contain the module of CMS including sub directories .On other hand I have to unzip the folder at server side.
Is there any way to accomplish this task?

Comment: Have you already try something?

Comment: no not at all.But I have uploaded images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've ever tried to upload & unzip the uploaded zip file (that contain XML file), unzip it & extract the XML data on the server side.

I used CodeIgniter-Unzip library to unzip the uploaded zip file, it's easy to use. Here is the source

[CodeIgniter-Unzip](http://getsparks.org/packages/unzip/show)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: yeah its useful but error Unable to load the requested class: unzip occurs! I don`t know why.

Comment: Have you placed the library in the right place? I place it in "system\libraries\Unzip.php". Note : I'm using Codigniter 1.7.2